# spl_autoload_register $this->function

Tags: php, this, spl-autoload-register

So I'm using `'spl_autoload_register'` on my `index` to load a bunch of `.classes` because I'm `lazy`, as you can see in my autoload construct below I'm also calling in `functions` from some of the `auto-loaded classes` to run my application.

In the scope of my project I'm not unable to reference for example `$this->function` inside another `function` of an `auto-loaded class`, maybe I'm not understanding how things are instantiated like this.

I would like the most efficient method for a project that would allow procedural and OOP structures but I really like using `$this` lol, how would I be able to use `$this` and to use it efficiently within my the classes loaded by my auto-loader, would I edit the init() maybe to allow `$this` ?

Pardon my ignorance making projects and not being up to date with coding structures.

surly `self::` should also be `static::` ?

classes->autoload->index

```
class autoloader {
    public static $loader;

    public static function init()
    {
        if(self::$loader == NULL) {
            self::$loader = new self();
        }
        return self::$loader;
    }   

    public function __construct() {
        spl_autoload_register(array(this, 'library'));
        request::request();
        template::render();

    }

    public function library($class) 
    {
        set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '/lib');
        spl_autoload_extensions('.class.php');
        spl_autoload($class);
    }


}
```

Comment: Why don't use composer?

Comment: I would if I knew what that was (O-o) ?

Comment: Just check http://getcomposer.org/

Comment: That looks very handy for building a project however I'm after a solution that can facilitate loading classes automatically that doesn't hurt the internal variable scope of the object, I'm still learning about OOP and would like to be able to use something that doesn't kill procedural and allows me to call internal variables $this->variable without it belonging to the auto load class autoload::variable